# Netsuite - mass update a field from a calculated field

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom field "views calculated" on an inventory item that is a calculated value. I cannot sort by calculated values so I need that value moved into a static field via a mass update. So once a day I want "views calculated" to move its value into "views"

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a support case. I had to do it via a workflow based on another saved search. So you can do it and it is a suiteAnswer. I didn't catch the number or I'd post it here. As a side note: Be careful testing scheduled workflows in testing mode. It only processes the top 20 records. I spent a day troubleshooting before I figured that out. That nugget is suiteAnswer id 36738 "Testing Scheduled Workflows"